# Why is the app-bar title change not working?

Tags: java, android

I have a collapsing toolbar. When it is collapsed, i set a app bar title, but once its expanded, i'm not able to remove the app bar title. The expand condition (verticalOffset == 0) is getting executed, but the title seem not getting changed.

```
public class MovieDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener{

    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_details);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

       ...

        collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);

        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

        ...
        setTitle("");
        ...

    }

    @Override
    public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) == appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange()) {
            //Closed
            setTitle("Tmovies");
            Log.i("test","Closed");

        } else if (verticalOffset == 0) {
            // Expanded
            setTitle("");
            Log.i("test","Expanded");
        } else {
            // Somewhere in between

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `toolbar.setTitle(...)` instead of `setTitle(...)`

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer `getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Title");`  instead of `tool.setTitle("My Title");` as the latter might not work after setSupportActionBar .